# Legend for multiple lines in Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, legend

I have 13 lines on a plot, each line corresponding to a set of data from a text file.  I'd like to label each line starting with the first set of data as 1.2, then subsequently 1.25, 1.30, to 1.80, etc., with each increment be 0.05.  If I were to type it out manually, it would be

```
legend('1.20','1.25','1.30', ...., '1.80')
```

However, in the future, I might have more than 20 lines on the graph.  So typing out each one is unrealistic. I tried creating a loop in the legend and it doesn't work.

How can I do this in a practical way?

---

```
N_FILES=13 ; 
N_FRAMES=2999 ; 
a=1.20 ;b=0.05 ; 
phi_matrix = zeros(N_FILES,N_FRAMES) ; 
for i=1:N_FILES
    eta=a + (i-1)*b ; 
    fname=sprintf('phi_per_timestep_eta=%3.2f.txt', eta) ; 
    phi_matrix(i,:)=load(fname);
end 
figure(1);
x=linspace(1,N_FRAMES,N_FRAMES) ;
plot(x,phi_matrix) ;
```

Need help here:

```
legend(a+0*b,a+1*b,a+2*b, ...., a+N_FILES*b)
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `x=1:N_FRAMES;`? Clearer I think. Actually you don't need x at all, `plot(phi_matrix);` should work.

Comment: @yuk: That would be better, but they would have to transpose `phi_matrix` so that it plots each column as a line.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to constructing the legend, you can also set the `DisplayName` property of a line so that the legend is automatically correct.

Thus, you could do the following:

```
N_FILES = 13;
N_FRAMES = 2999;
a = 1.20; b = 0.05;

% # create colormap (look for distinguishable_colors on the File Exchange)
% # as an alternative to jet
cmap = jet(N_FILES);

x = linspace(1,N_FRAMES,N_FRAMES);

figure(1)
hold on % # make sure new plots aren't overwriting old ones

for i = 1:N_FILES
    eta = a + (i-1)*b ; 
    fname = sprintf('phi_per_timestep_eta=%3.2f.txt', eta); 
    y = load(fname);

    %# plot the line, choosing the right color and setting the displayName
    plot(x,y,'Color',cmap(i,:),'DisplayName',sprintf('%3.2f',eta));
end 

% # turn on the legend. It automatically has the right names for the curves
legend
```

Answer (score 6):

Use 'DisplayName' as a plot() property, and call your legend as

```
legend('-DynamicLegend');
```

My code looks like this:

```
x = 0:h:xmax;                                  % get an array of x-values
y = someFunction;                              % function
plot(x,y, 'DisplayName', 'Function plot 1');   % plot with 'DisplayName' property
legend('-DynamicLegend',2);                    % '-DynamicLegend' legend
```

source: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/legend-semi-documented-feature/

Answer (score 5):

`legend` can also take a cell list of strings as an argument.  Try this:

```
legend_fcn = @(n)sprintf('%0.2f',a+b*n);
legend(cellfun(legend_fcn, num2cell(0:N_FILES) , 'UniformOutput', false));
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would probably be to create a column vector of the numbers to use as your labels, convert them to a formatted character array with `N_FILES` rows using the function [NUM2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html), then pass this as a single argument to [LEGEND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/legend.html):

```
legend(num2str(a+b.*(0:N_FILES-1).','%.2f'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.itu.dk/stud/speciale/segmentering/Matlab6p5/help/techdoc/ref/legend.html) I found through Google:

> `legend(string_matrix)` adds a legend containing the rows of the matrix `string_matrix` as labels. This is the same as `legend(string_matrix(1,:),string_matrix(2,:),...)`.

So basically, it looks like you can construct a matrix somehow to do this.

An example:

```
strmatrix = ['a';'b';'c';'d'];

x = linspace(0,10,11);
ya = x;
yb = x+1;
yc = x+2;
yd = x+3;

figure()
plot(x,ya,x,yb,x,yc,x,yd)
legend(strmatrix)
```